# User information by username

Tags: php, pdo

I have code:

```
$query = dbConnect()->prepare("SELECT * FROM players");
$query->execute();

foreach ($query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row) {
    echo 'Slapyvardis: '. $row['Vardas'] . '<br>Pinigai: '.$row['Pinigai'] . '<br>Patirtis: '.$row['XP'];
}
```

I need that information to be displayed by username:

`$query->bindParam(":Vardas", $_POST["Vardas"]);` or `$_SESSION["vardas"] = $row["vardas"];`

How can i do that?

Comment: You want to query by individuals?

Comment: Add `WHERE Vardas = :Vardas` to the query.

Comment: Sorry for my bad language. I have simple login script, when i log in i have the player information button. I wanna see information by logged user(points, xp) that hide other.

Comment: I need that get my name by session or etc and get information by name.